# Does WebUSB support timeouts?

Tags: webusb

Usb libraries always support setting timeouts on operation with device. And this is important feature for soft which works with usb devices, because that's how you can understand that device don't answer to your command. I look through WebUSB Api and look's like it's not support timeouts at the moment.

Is it true? Is the only way is to manually start timeouts before every usb operation, and stop timeout after operation success?

Answer (score 2):

WebUSB does not currently support transfer timeouts or aborting transfers because after surveying the various platform APIs for USB it did not seem possible to implement them in a consistent way. Ideally it would be possible to cancel a transfer by removing it from the USB controller's transfer schedule. This is possible on Linux with the `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB` ioctl and timeouts are supported on macOS using `ReadPipeAsyncTO()` and similar functions. On Windows however the only way to cancel a transfers is to call `WinUsb_AbortPipe()` which affects all pending transfers on the pipe, not just the one that timed out.

If you need to react to a device not replying to a USB request in a timely fashion then doing so manually with `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` is the best option. Keep in mind that USB transfer itself will remain active and could complete at a later time.